# what is the meaning of the comma in instr function?

Tags: excel, vba

i am currently tasked to improve the existing vba file. However, i am unable to contact with the person who did this code. So may i know what does the comma in first = InStr(2, sl, ",", 1)  means? Because i went to find the comma in the csv file but i couldn't find at all using both ctrl F and also manually searching for commas in between string.

```
Private Sub readdata(filename As String, i As Integer)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim sl As String
Dim first As Integer
Dim second As Integer
Dim j As Long
j = 2
Set fs2 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set o_file = fs2.OpenTextFile(filename, 1, TristateFalse) 


 Do While Left(sl, 1) = "#"   
 sl = o_file.readline
 Loop

 Do While o_file.atendofstream <> True 'atendofstream = Read-only property that returns True if the file pointer is at the end of a TextStream file; False if it is not.
    sl = o_file.readline
    first = InStr(2, sl, ",", 1)  
    second = InStr(first + 2, sl, ",", 1)
    If second = 0 Then
         second = Len(sl) + 1
         End If
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function

Answer (score 2):

> [InStr
>   function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function)

The `","` is searching a real comma in your string `sl`

And yes, CSV means *Comma Separated Values*, but does not mean that there is a real comma in all CSV files. That would explain why it returns 0.

Answer (score 1):

The [syntax of InStr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function) is as follows:

```
InStr([ start ], string1, string2, [ compare ])
```

So `InStr(2, sl, ",", 1)` searches for `,` in `sl`, where the starting position is `2` and the `1` at the end means there is a textual comparison.

Mind that .csv often is seperated by another char than `,`, e.g. `;`

Answer (score 1):

> InStr( [start], string, substring, [compare] )
>
> start: Optional. It is the starting position for the search
>
> string: The string to search within.
>
> substring: The substring that you want to find.
>
> compare: Optional. It is the type of comparison to perform